# How can use invert grep after pipe?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to list directory disk usage in a fileserver. 
I also want to ignore the error messages. Here is my command:

```
du -sh * | grep -v "Permission denied" | sort -n
```

The result still contains the permission denied lines:

```
du: cannot access './myFile1/': Permission denied
du: cannot access './myFile2/': Permission denied
du: cannot access './myFile3/': Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are sent to stderr, send stderr through the pipe as well. `2>&1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the "Permission denied" is sent through standard error, not through standard output.

If you don't want this information, just silence it by redirecting stderr to /dev/null:

```
du -sh * 2>/dev/null | sort -n
```

This happens with all these error messages:

```
$ touch a
$ ls a asfasd
ls: cannot access asfasd: No such file or directory
a
$ ls a asfasd | grep cannot
ls: cannot access asfasd: No such file or directory
$ ls a asfasd 2>/dev/null  
a
```

Comment: Yeah, that.  I was just typing the same thing, but slowly.  :-)  The redirect is better than an inverted grep, because you need know nothing about the variety of errors that might occur.

Comment: It works, but can you explain what happens under the hood? What does the 2 mean?

Comment: @fonzane `2` refers to the stderr. That is, the output that is "erroneous". If you say `ls somefile alsdjflaksdj`, and `somefile` exists and the second one does not, then `1` (stdout) will prompt the info of this first file, while `2` will say "ls: cannot access..." as an error.